# how do I put checkboxes or other content in a scrollpane?

Tags: flash, components, checkbox, scrollpane

How would I put buttons or checkboxes in a scroll pane so it will scroll.
I tried adding them as children but they seem to be attached to the scrollpane but not inside. they do not scroll they just extend out of it?

Is there a way to put content in a scrollpane besides text.  The problem I'm trying to solve is dealing with a large number of checkboxes in a small area. The checkboxes are dynamically generated from the script.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a standard scrollpane, then it should have a `.source` property. If you add the name of your checkbox, it will get into the scrollpane.

Now, if you want to add complex content, I suggest you to create an empty movieclip and put that into the scrollpane. Anything you want to add to the scrollpane, add it to this movieclip.

```
//create your container
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
//you don't need to add it to the displaylist (addChild(mc))

//now set it as the source of your scrollpane
your_scrollpane.source = mc;

//any time you add a new item
mc.addChild(your_checkbox);

//you can set the properties
your_checkbox.x = 0;
your_checkbox.y = 0;

//and refresh the scrollpane
your_scrollpane.update();
```

You can also setup your mc before making it as the source of your scrollpane.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that helps a lot.  ONly thing is that some of the text is cut off on the checkbox which is in the movieclip which is the source for the scrollpane. Changing the scrollpane width does not work. Changing the movieclip width makes it look stretched?  Any ideas why the text is getting cut off?